# How do I create a live connection between the data source (excel) and Power BI for the visuals?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I need to make a live connection to an excel file which is my data source and Power BI that I am supposed to use for the visualizations that I will be making. Any idea on how to do this?

I have created all relevant pages, now I just need to make the live connection.

Comment: Excel data source [do not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources#data-sources-e-g) Live, nor DirectQuery connections. Which is expected, because Excel is not a database, and you can't send queries to it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A live connection is when the data source is on the computer along with the Power BI report. So I assume as long as they are not separated, that the connection is "live".

Comment: No, Live connection means that you don't have a model in the Power BI report at all, and you use the model from the underlying AAS, SSAS or PBI data source.